# Catching exception not working when running under gdb (gdbserver)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gdb, mingw-w64

I am cross compiling my project on Ubuntu 20.04 using mingw-w64 (so targeting Windows). I am doing a static link.

When running my code on Windows, thrown exception handling work just fine and as expected. However, when running under gdbserver, I get this:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of helper::fileops::fileOps::fileNotFound`

This happens even though I have a break point set inside the catch block. I guess, somehow, gdbserver is interfering with the normal try/catch operation and the exception travels all the way up to the library handler, which terminates the process. Again, without gdb my code is catching the exception (and printing my message on screen).

I installed both mingw-w64 and gdb/gdbserver from the Ubuntu repository.

Here are the version
`/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gdb --version   GNU gdb (GDB) 9.1`

and

`/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --version   x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 9.3-posix 20200320`

I am not sure exactly where is the problem. Is it in mingw-w64? Or in gdb/gdbsever? Or a version incompatibility between the two?

Just to be sure, my catch statement is catch (...) so I should be catching anything and everything!!

EDIT

I created a sample program, which goes as

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
int main()
{
  std::cout<<"Before the try block" << std::endl;

  try {
    throw std::runtime_error("Test exception");
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Catched the exception" << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout<<"After the try block" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled using this

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -static hello.cpp -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -o hello

When running outside gdb, I get this output

```
Before the try block
Catched the exception
After the try block
```

But under gdbserver, I get

```
Listening on port 2345
Remote debugging from host 192.168.70.8, port 44782
Before the try block
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

Child exited with status 3
```

EDIT
The solution is simply, just upgrade gdb and gdbserver to version 12 (actually only gdbserver is you are running remotely).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The mcve was added. Since then I continued to look around. Still no solution. But I have an idea: could this be related to the exception handling model (sjlj vs seh vs dwarf)? Both the debugger and the compiler come from the Ubuntu repository so I would assume they use the same model. But if not could this explain what I am seeing?

Comment: I can reproduce this with gdb 11.2, but no longer with the upcoming gdb 12. And I think it was fixed with [this commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;f=gdb/nat/windows-nat.c;h=183be222907a6f419bd71f70ee650989026f0188).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The author of the commit does think it relates to the issue I am having. However, you are correct, gdb version 12 fixes the issue, regardless of which commit actually did the trick...